# posting photos to album provides different insights if posted through API or Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Were pulling our hair with this problem trying to report accurate engagement on Facebook albums. One problem is what shows up in page_ID/feed. If an album and photos are created with the API (create empty album, then add photos individually) the API returns one story/post for every photo. If an album and photos are created within Facebook, the API returns only one story/post for the entire album. This last behavior is what we want, but we would like to be able to do through the API. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak specifically to pulling back content via page_ID/feed, but I've managed to get multiple photos uploaded to a single album to appear as one story in the user's feed, which  may carry over to the API GET request you want as well.

The way I've gotten this to work is by using the [Batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/) to combine all the photo creation requests into one single batch.  When uploaded all at once in a batch, they get consolidated as a single story in the user's feed.  With any luck, that'll carry over to the page_id/feed endpoint for you as well!